# Make any window execute in maximized mode

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have an issue related with Windows 10 I'd like to solve.

Everytime I execute a program, it launches in a reduced window or maximized, but not aligned with the screen.

I've searched arround the web and the most common solution to this is right-clicking over the program, going to "properties" and select "maximized" under the "execute" option. This is a solution, but however, this happens with almost program in my computer, and doing this with any executable I have is a long task to do.

I was wondering if there's a registry option to make all windows execute in maximized mode when possible, instead of doing it manually per each executable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window size property is usually set on the shortcut.

Go find the shortcut, right-click and go to Properties and look for the Run drop-down. Change this to Maximised.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal setting. That is a function of each (and every) application.

Office Apps will open full screen if saved full screen. Other apps will do this as well. Put another way, these apps remember if they were being used Full Screen or Windowed and then save the way they were used/

Numerous other apps open in a Window and need to be maximized.

Very few apps only open in Full Screen.

I set all apps to open in a Window